# WPF MVVM DataContext becomes null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I'm facing an issue in my WPF program. I don't know why but sometimes (randomly) my DataContext in my View becomes null. 
I'm calling a function in my view using the mvvm messenger in MvvmLight library.

```
private void MyView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<MessageType>(this, HandleMessage);
}
```

This function show a progress dialog and need to access the DataContext (the VM) to call a function.

```
private async void HandleMessage()
{
    var metroWindow = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow);
    var controller = await metroWindow.ShowProgressAsync("Title", "Message");
    controller.SetIndeterminate();

    await ((MyViewModel)DataContext).MyFunction();

    await controller.CloseAsync();
}
```

I obtained the following error in my logs:

```
---message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
---source: MyProgram
---stacktrace:    at Path.To.MyView.<HandleMessage>d__11.MoveNext() in myfile.xaml.cs
```

The program is actually never updating the DataContext, that's why I'm a bit confused. If someone has an idea to help?

Comment: Your ViewModel should Handle your message and call a "MessageService" to display your mahapps Dialog

Comment: You haven't shown at what point you are setting the DataContext; and you say "the program is actually never updating the DataContext"; but if the value is sometimes not null then *something* must be setting it, or it must be inheriting it. Please clarify what is setting it.

Comment: Are you setting your DataContext explicitly in code or XAML or implicitly via ContentControl and ResourceDictionary in XAML?  Need more info on when and where your DataContext is being set or if it is being set at all.

Comment: @Cedric : What are you thinking with "call a MessageService" please?

Comment: @user1286901 I am defining the DataContext in a ResourceDictionary in XAML

Comment: @sansquer can you please show the snippet of XAML from your ResourceDictionary where it is being set.  Usually you will have a `DataTemplate` that hooks your View with your ViewModel.  Is your DataContext ever not null?

Comment: @sansquer a class that manage your mahapps dialogues for all your application.This service would expose a method "ShowMessage(string title, string message)" and "CloseMessage()" this way you could declare this service directly in your ViewModel and call your methods